# ChromeDriver support for clicking when zoom is not 100%

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use chromedriver on Windows. When the zoom level in the browser is set to anything different from 100% element.click() may work incorrectly. Instead of clicking the specified element it clicks another element (possibly located at the position where the original element would have been at 100% zoom). In my case, I can't control zoom level on the browser. So setting it back to 100% as in the GIF below is not an option.

I knew this was a limitation for [IEDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration):

> The browser zoom level must be set to 100%

But the chromedriver [website](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/clicking-issues) doesn't explicitly mention that. And I wonder is it a known limitation or a bug?

Are there any workarounds for this?

Here is a gif demonstrating the issue:[image: GIF demonstrating clicking issue]
The demo page and the script are [here](https://gist.github.com/SergeyAvd/8d54212f9a6ed2f296e8a03aa5f79fae).

UPDATE:

- Chrome version: 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (32-bit)
- chromedriver
  version: 2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a)

Comment: I think it's possible. Selenium calculate the center point of the element, then click at the center point. When zoom is not 100%,  Selenium is possible to get center point value under zoom 100%.  I think you can write script to prove my guess is correct or not by get the left-up corner location of the element with zoom 100% and not 100% to see they are same or not.  If same, it's a issue/feature web driver  need to consider.

Comment: Could you show the implementation code and ensure that the Webelement is not cached. I do not think selenium have the issue when we find the element and perform the click at the same time.

Comment: @TonyBui my implementation: `return driver.findElement(By.id('box-'+id)).click();` I believe it doesn't cache an element. For more detail please see the gist I linked above.

Comment: What is the version of chromedriver and chrome browser?

Comment: @ChandaKorat please see the update above

Comment: @SergeyAvdeev have you tried with Click by JavaScript?

Comment: @ChandaKorat the gif above demonstrates the effect of `click()` by WebDriverJS  API. Separately I tried `driver.executeScript('document.getElementById("box-99").click()');` - executing JavaScript inside of the page (if that's what you mean). It works for my testing page but it doesn't quite work for some real life websites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=628) and is tracked in the chromedriver bug tracker.